# How to verify if a cloud formation stack has auto rollback enabled when stack creation/update is failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

During the creation or update of a CloudFormation Stack if a failure occurs, the cloud formation stack rollback is triggered as long as Disable Rollback parameter value is set as false.
I want to know if I can check the Disable Rollback parameter value from the aws console as I don't have access to the code where cloud formation config is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you can do it in console, but using AWS CLI you can use [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) which returns `DisableRollback` option.